# django: is it possible to keep a model field updated with a model method?

Tags: python, django

So basically I have a model Equipment that has foreign key calibration. I would like to have a field in Equipment as 'latest_calibrated_date' which get the 'cal_date' from the newest created calibration. Here is what I have now:

```
def latest_calibration_date(self):
        return Calibration.objects.filter(cal_asset__id = self.id).order_by('-id')[0].cal_date
```

However, for the purpose of some other apps, I would like to make this not a method but a field. So I am thinking about use a latest_calibration_date = models.DateField() and update it every time a new Calibration is added. How could I do this?

Comment: Override the save method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah that sounds like what I would like to have. Could you elaborate a bit more on how exactly could I do that pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Daniel Roseman* pointed out, you can override `save` method on `Calibration` model. For example:

```
class Calibration(model.Model):
    # your fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Calibration, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # update latest calibration date
```

You can store your parameter in many ways, for example by creating `Parameter` model for storing your variables.

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

and then again in `save`:

```
import time

p = Parameter.objects.get(key='LATEST_CALIBRATION_DATE')
p.value = time.time() # save in UNIX timestamp
p.save()
```

or whatever format you like.